# Difference between feel regret and feel regretful?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I made up this sentence.

> People **feel regret** after breaking up with their spouse.
>   People **feel regretful** after breaking up with their spouse.

Is there any difference in nuance?

Comment: There is not really much difference at all in constructions like these, noun vs. adjective. Certainly there is no meaningful distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in meaning.

If you are/feel regretful, you feel regret. So you can use either a noun or an adjective after the verb feel.  However, the first sentence with the noun "regret" is more common.